# Error With Validation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started to code and I already got an error , I have tried different ways but it is not working , can someone tell me what is causing the error?

```
itemsneeded=''
while not itemsneeded.isnumeric() and int(itemsneeded)<5:
    itemsneeded=(input('How many items do you need?'))
```

error: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"

Comment: `int("")` doesn't know what int to give you. Can you tell us what you want to accomplish?

Comment: do you mean "or" in the condition rather than "and"?

Comment: I am gessing you are trying to cast itemsneeded to an int somehow. am I correct?

Comment: If you want to cast an empty string to an `int`, use `int(itemsneeded) if itemsneeded else 0`

Comment: @L3viathan just allowing the user to enter a number which is less than 5

Comment: also, @XiaotianPei is right, both your conditions CANNOT be true at the same time. itemsneeded cannot be nonnumeric and smaller 5 at the same time.

Comment: THE USE OF OR WORKED THANKS !!!!!!!!

Comment: but i need both validations ?!

Comment: Both validations will apply if you use or: If it isn't a number OR if the number is smaller then 5, you'll ask the user again.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looping "infinitely" and breaking out of the loop when all requirements are met:

```
while True:
    itemsneeded = input("How many items do you need?")
    if itemsneeded.isnumeric() and int(itemsneeded) < 5:
        break
```

Comment: @Azizoasf Please use the checkmark next to the answer to let others on the site know that this is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
while True:
    try:    
        itemsneeded = int(input("How many items do you need?"))
    except ValueError: 
        print("Not an number")
        break
    if int(itemsneeded) < 5:
        break
```

Comment: This is practically the same as the existing answer, but Python2, when the question is tagged with Python3

Comment: I thought raw_input was only a python2 function?

Comment: Thanks,reflected back changes